# A Scheme compiler for ARM processors

Tags: compiler-construction, embedded, scheme

Is there a Scheme compiler (not interpreter) for ARM processors, specifically Cortex-M3? I'm looking for a compiler, not an interpreter, to get a predictable and small execution times on a (relatively) slow processors. It probably will omit some parts of specification (continuations, maybe); that's fine.

I should note that I only have a 8 kB (maybe 2-4 times more) of RAM.

I'll try to use everything in the answers, and then reply with my findings. That may take some time, through.

Comment: Bigloo is known to work. Stalin is likely to work (but I have not tried it with ARM). Practically, any other Scheme to C compiler should be ok as well.

Comment: And, btw., do you really need Scheme? Would not something like BitC be more appropriate in an embedded environment?

Comment: @SK-logic, if Bigloo "is known to work", can you provide a link? Cortex-M3s are from low-end segment of ARM controllers, they cannot run Linux, for example, and I don't see any support for bare uCs in Bigloo. Also, it's quite big. BitC looks like a good project, but I'd like to stick with something more standardized and documented.

Comment: @SK-logic, the problem with most Scheme-to-C compilers is that they require a runtime, which is often quite big and sometimes dependent on OS features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484030/lisp-on-embedded-platforms) was on Common Lisp, but [one particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484030/lisp-on-embedded-platforms/5485906#5485906) referenced [Picobit](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/stamourv/papers/picobit.pdf), which is essentially a Scheme for microcontrollers. It very well fits in my conditions, as the paper says it can work on as little as 7 kb of memory.

I've decided to [fork](http://github.com/whitequark/picobit) Picobit and port it to ARM processors.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/)?

Comment: Very interesting! I'll look into the way of making it work with Cortex-M3 CPUs, through. They're quite limited in RAM.

Comment: Chicken Scheme is indeed a very good piece of software, but its runtime library is [around 240k](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/faq#how-can-i-obtain-smaller-executables) in size, and I don't even know the RAM footprint. Sadly, that's a bit too much. (Also, it lacks any support for running on bare-metal microcontrollers, but that's less of a problem.)

Comment: @whitequark: ah, sorry.  I don't have any experience running scheme in constrained environments, but I had used chicken scheme to compile to C before so I had hoped that would work out.

Answer (score 1):

[Gambit-C](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) also provides Scheme to C compiler.
Also take a look on [Stalin](http://community.schemewiki.org/?Stalin)

Comment: As far as I can see, Gambit has a very big runtime, and Stalin generates quite bloated code -- maybe it is really faster, but definitely also RAM-hungry, which is unacceptable.

Comment: Out of the box the gambit runtime is very big, but there has been some work done to trim a lot of the fat, and only provide enough runtime for what is needed, rather then every gambit primitive and function.